# Adding Gstreamer support to an android NDK project

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, gstreamer

I've installed the latest android SDK bundle as well as the latest android NDK on windows 7.

I've set up my environment and am able to run the hellojni example from the NDK installation package.

But when i try to add Gstreamer support according to the creating new projects section of the [gstreamer android tutorial page](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+Android+development), I get this error when i try to build my project:

```
GStreamer      : [COMPILE] => gst-build/gstreamer_android.c
gst-build/gstreamer_android.c:1:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
E:/GstreamerAndroid/sdk/share/gst-android/ndk-build//gstreamer.mk:167: recipe for 
target `gst-build/gstreamer_android.o' failed
make: *** [gst-build/gstreamer_android.o] Error 1
```

I tried a few solutions such as setting my path variable to the jni.h in NDK (eg. ndkr8e\platforms\android-14\arch-arm\usr\include) but nothing works.

Can anyone suggest any other solutions?

**EDIT:** As suggested my iljan, i downloaded an older version of the android NDK (r8d), and i got my project to compile. But i don't understand whether the problem was from my side or a bug in the NDK version. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment to this [issue](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=62697), seems that adding

```
...
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

SYSROOT := /opt/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
...
```

all work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem for me with the NDK version r8e:
I have set up the environment (eclipse, android sdk, ndk, cygwin) and successfuly compiled the hello-jni. But the Gstreamer Tutorial1 won't compile.
My NDK install path was "C:\android\android-ndk-r8e"

But I was lucky enough to have previous ndk installed elsewhere on my disk, so I just copied it next to the never install, all files from:
"C:\Program Files\Android\ndk\android-ndk-r8d" to "C:\android\android-ndk-r8d" and changed NDK location path in Eclipse: Window->Preferences->Android->NDK to this new folder.

Voila! It compiles now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean to say that i should install an earlier version of the NDK? It seems to me that the problem got fixed for you because you had spaces in your path..which is not the case for me.

Comment: Yes, I mean that previous version of NDK compiles GStreamer Tutorial1 just fine.
And no, my problem was not due to spaces in the path:
I had Eclipse pointing to the newest NDK at "C:\android\android-ndk-r8e" and it was'nt working. I found a previous revision (r8d) of NDK already on my disk and just copied it next to the latest one, than pointed Eclipse to it and everything works now. 
That's why I say I was lucky - quick googling does not give any links to a previous NDK download.

Comment: You're right, it worked! i managed to download the android r8d version using this link: http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8d-windows.zip. Changed the path to this new folder, and it compiled! Thanks!

Comment: rubndsouza - did you manage to get other tutorials built? My system hangs tryng to build Tutorials 2-5.

Comment: OK, I got all the tutorials built, but it is more of a manual workaround:
As I'm with Eclipse Juno on Windows 7 I do it like this:
`1. Add new android project from existing tutorial source
2. Add native support to the project
3. Try to build the project. The build hangs. Go to Task manager and kill make.exe (sometimes more than once). Then the build completes.
4. Run as android Applicaation - Eclipse tries to rebuild but hangs again. Killing make.exe helps.`

Comment: Yes, i was able to run all...eclipse hung a bit when i add native support but i restarted and everything was fine.

Comment: Were you able to run tutorial 3? I get an "error received from element videotestsrc0" on my android emulator.

Comment: I run tutorial 3 with modified pipeline to display my RDP stream. And I run it on Android device, because emulator is not able to decode and display the video and crashes with many errors