# Adding Native support to gstreamer tutorial won't finish

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, gstreamer

I'm following this: 
http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+Android+development

I'm using the Windows x86 ADT bundle, the Windows x86 r9d NDK, and the Gstreamer SDK linked to in the guide.

I was able to get the first tutorial to add native support, build, and run.  Then I tried the 3rd tutorial, and Eclipse becomes unresponsive. Same thing happened with the 2nd tutorial.  I left it to do it over the weekend in case it just took a long time. When I change anything for another attempt I delete the tutorial folder completely and use a fresh copy from the zip file.  I have also remove the ADT bundle completely and started over from scratch. 
If I cancel, I have the expected build errors of missing `import com.gstreamer.GStreamer;`
The GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID value is set to C:/gstreamer
The NDK Location is C:\android-ndk-r8d

I switched to using r8d as recommended in: [Adding Gstreamer support to an android NDK project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077836/adding-gstreamer-support-to-an-android-ndk-project)

One comment also suggests adding to the gstreamer.mk file:

`ifndef SYSROOT
   SYSROOT := $(NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT)/$(TARGET_PLATFORM)/arch-$(TARGET_ARCH)
endif`
I attempted this but there is a gstreamer_prebuilt.mk file it may be using instead.

My only clue is that Tutorial 1 does not use gstreamer plugins and the tutorials that do not work use plugins.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Edit: I tried using android-ndk-r7c also.
      Then I deleted the ADT bundle and tried going the "Use an existing IDE" route, same result.
      I'm going to try a different machine, and also see if I can compile it without eclipse, but I would love to hear any guess on what's going on.

Edit2: I watched a youtube video of someone setting this up (as far as I can tell he adds the NDK manually adding a build program and pointing to the ndk-build.cmd file):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKfAELFdf9A

This seemed to work but I was still missing `import com.gstreamer.GStreamer;` so I closed the tutorial 2 project, built and ran tutorial 1, opened tutorial 2 again, cleaned, built, and it ran.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I watched a youtube video of someone setting this up (as far as I can tell he adds the NDK manually adding a build program and pointing to the ndk-build.cmd file):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKfAELFdf9A

This seemed to work but I was still missing import com.gstreamer.GStreamer; so I closed the tutorial 2 project, built and ran tutorial 1, opened tutorial 2 again, cleaned, built, and it ran.

Problem solved.